# Crash Reporting & Analytics for Android TV App

Tags: firebase, crash-reports, crashlytics, flurry, android-tv

is there any framework/library specific for android TV application, which can be integrated easily?

I've searched out and just found some frameworks/libraries, such as Firebase, Fabric/Crashlytics, HockeyApp, Appteligent,Instabug, FLURRY, etc. But all of them have got a SDK just for a native android application (mostly mobile apps) and there isn’t any specific one for the android TV app. 
Furthermore I would like to analyze and track all kind of TV devices with a complete overview and details. Surely, I want to know which framework/library free is and also support all kinds of events.

Thanks,

HaMa

Answer (score 1):

For our Android TV app we're using Hockeyapp (free for up to two apps) for crash reporting and Localytics for our analytics logging (not free). Both of those services automatically log device model (the Android TV model like Sony Bravia, Nexus Player, etc) as well as the Android operating system they're running.

You can find how to get access to these features in their respective documentation.

With all of that being said, Firebase is a free option which Google is trying to push for all new apps which supports both crash reporting AND analytics. I'm assuming that it also automatically logs OS and device model information since that is a pretty common requirement for this type of thing.

A good rule of thumb is anything that works for Android mobile will also work for Android TV - at least that's how I've felt so far.

Answer (score 0):

Sentry does crash reporting for backend and frontend platforms, including [Android](https://github.com/joshdholtz/Sentry-Android). (full disclosure, I work at Sentry). The library is actively maintained.

WRT which platform is free, Sentry itself has been open source (all the clients and the server) for 8 years, if you'd like to run your own servers. Pricing for the hosted service is [here](http://getsentry.com/pricing).